# when should i create a separate table for fields?

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

Let's say i have this SQL table :

```
CREATE TABLE `article` (
 `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `family` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `sub_family` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NOT NULL,
 `price` float NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Here every `family` of articles has one or multiple `sub_family`

should i create another table that has all possible combinations of `family` and `sub_family` and refer to it using a `foreing key` ?

---

Data example :

[image]

Comment: are you going to use `sub_family` for another purpose? if not then just stay as it is.

Comment: @BoykeFerdinandes when the food menu is complete there will be many articles to choose from, so the user doesnt have to look for "Coffee" in a pool of 20 buttons, i'll make it easier by classifying them into families and sub_families.
It's for UI clarity basically.

Comment: Sketch out the `SELECTs`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to fix redundancy completely, please try the following table:

```
create table `family` (
 `family_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `family` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `parent_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`family_id`),
 index idx_family_sub (`family`, `parent_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `article` (
 `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 `family_id` int(11) not null,
 `price` float NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`article_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

The data in there 2 table may look like:

```
mysql> select * from family order by family_id;
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
| family_id | family      | parent_id |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
|         1 | Main Course |         0 |
|         2 | Beverage    |         0 |
|         3 | Pasta       |         1 |
|         4 | Hot Drinks  |         2 |
|         5 | Cold Drinks |         2 |
+-----------+-------------+-----------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from article;
+------------+-----------+-----------+-------+
| article_id | name      | family_id | price |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-------+
|          1 | Spaghetti |         3 |   600 |
|          2 | Penne     |         3 |   500 |
|          3 | Coffee    |         4 |   100 |
|          4 | Penne     |         5 |   150 |
+------------+-----------+-----------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The query to get all data like data example is :

```
mysql> select
    ->        a.article_id, a.name, f2.family as family, f.family as sub_family, a.price
    -> from `article2` a
    ->     join family2 f on a.family_id = f.family_id
    ->     join family2 as f2 on f.parent_id = f2.family_id;
+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------+
| article_id | name      | family      | sub_family  | price |
+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------+
|          1 | Spaghetti | Main Course | Pasta       |   600 |
|          2 | Penne     | Main Course | Pasta       |   500 |
|          3 | Coffee    | Beverage    | Hot Drinks  |   100 |
|          4 | Penne     | Beverage    | Cold Drinks |   150 |
+------------+-----------+-------------+-------------+-------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

From my perspective, this table is used to save food menu data, and it should be very small. I think it's OK to create a dedicated table to save family and sub_family.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing to prevent duplicate values, families from being used as subfamilies, or even that the `parent_id` is a valid value... and you have to perform a join just to see the valid combinations.  That does not seem like reducing redundancy.

Answer (score 0):

I read your question and comments as well. I think you can create two different tables that'll for sure reduce the data redundancy and complexity.

You can create Family as a parent table:
In Family table you can declare a unique key(which you can use further for foreign key referencing) for each Family and sub-Family pair for example:

**Family:**

```
ID   | Family_name | Subfamily
1       Beverage     Hot Drinks
2       Beverage     cold Drinks
3       main course  Pasta
```

And you can create another table for Articles which will be connected with parent via foreign key reference ID.

**Article:**

```
  ID  |  Family | Name       | Price
  1       2      Milk Shake    100.00
  2       1      Coffee        200.00
```

You can try something like this. I hope you find this easy to understand.

[image]

Comment: i already see the family "Beverage" twice in the new table, this didnt fix the redundancy problem.

Comment: For that, if you want you can again split that table into two one for family and another for sub family. but i don't think there will be so many Sub Families under one Family and for this small numbers of sub families creating overhead of adding another table may not be that much beneficial. That's why i haven't created a separate table. But there can be so many Articles where redundancy can be problem that must be considered. And i am considering redundancy problem in article table.

Comment: Please lemme know what do you think about this? Do you think there will be so many like 50-100 or even more Sub Families under one Family?
If not then i think you can use just two table as per the above post.

Comment: I belive you're right, even if there is a redundancy in subfamilies it can be neglected since they're so few, Thank you very much :)

Comment: If you found this answer helpful then please mark it as an answer.
Thank you so much.

Comment: If you create 3 different tables for this small purpose. Every time while fetching records there will be extra over-head to join three table by looking at there foreign keys, which leads to increase in complexity and data retrieving time. So please be selective while deciding the design.

Comment: Yes yes ! like i said in another comment below , joining 3 tables seems to over-complicate the issue, you're right.